How to keep rig from deforming mesh in its rest pose?
The bones in my rig appear to be placed correctly, and I'm happy with the way it moves, but applying the armature to my model causes its elbows and knees to appear "inflated".

before parenting the model to the rig

after parenting the model to the rig
I have a deliberately low-poly model, and I'd prefer to not add any more geometry onto it, but I'll do it if I absolutely must.

Have you applied the scale of the armature and pose of the bones to be the resting pose before parenting the mesh?
Share your file if you can

@Cornivius Yes, yes I have

hello maybe the Pole Angle of the IK constraint? Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Like moonboots said, if these are your IK controllers then they are not in line with the knee so after the IK takes place the knee is going to be pointing outwards, even if the bones don't look rotated in edit mode.

Try putting them in front of the knee and see if that helps
